# Running a focused Groovy unit test from SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Groovy unit test class that has many unit tests.  In the JUnit way I would normally run with the test function selected, but that doesn't work.

How do you run a focused unit test from STS?  I know it's possible on the command line, but I'd like to do it from the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the entire suite once: Right-click on the file -> Run as -> JUnit test.

After all of the tests appear, you can terminate the process.  Then select the unit test you want to run, right-click -> Run.

Alternatively, open your launch configuration dialog, create a JUnit test launch configuration.  Select your project, package, and test class.  You can also choose a unit test.